# Google cloud messaging error service not available

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm following this tutorial

http://javapapers.com/android/google-cloud-messaging-gcm-for-android-and-push-notifications/

and i did every thing but when registering id im getting the following error :

Registered with GCM server.ERROR : SERVICE NOT AVAILABLE

im testing on my actual device HTC with android 2.3.5 because my machine doesn't support Hax , time and date on my device is correct and i have google play services installed , and still getting the same error , any solution ??

Comment: you need google play services apk installed. Try testing on a real device

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your code just try to register again with GCM by opening the app again. I have the same problem when I first install the app I was getting the same error but when I open app again I got registered

Comment: i have this problem since yesterday and still no fix , what else could be the reason for this message ?